# How to process multiple yarn jobs in certain order?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am submitting multiple spark jobs in the following manner -

```
someCollection.foreach(m => {
    ..some code
    sparkSubmitClass.run(m.name)
    .. some code
})
```

where sparkSubmitClass.run() method basically uses a shell script which has $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit and other related parameters.

The problem is that this code submits all the spark jobs in one go. What I want to achieve is - submit a job, then submit another job only when the earlier one finishes. This is because someCollection is ordered and the next job depends on data created by the previous job(s).

sparkSubmitClass.run() is on the following lines -

```
def run(appName: String)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) = {
val command = s"sparkJob.sh $appName"
val processBuilder = Process(command)
val pio = new ProcessIO(_ => (),
  stdout => {
    scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stdout)
      .getLines.foreach(str => log.info(s"spark-submit: Application 
       Name=$appName stdout='${str.replace("'", "\\'")}'"))
  },
  stderr => {
    val lines = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(stderr).getLines().toBuffer
    lines.foreach(str => log.info(s"spark-submit: Application Name=$appName 
        stderr='${str.replace("'", "\\'")}'"))
    lines.flatMap(parseLineForApplicationUrl).headOption.foreach(appId => 
     appId)
  })

  val process = processBuilder.run(pio)
  val exitVal = process.exitValue() //returns 0 as soon as application is 
  submitted
}
```

And sparkJob.sh is basically -

```
MAIN_CLASS="com.SomeClassHavingRDDAndHiveOperations"
APPNAME=$1

JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=$WORKER_DIRECT_MEM_SIZE -
XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"

SPARK_HOME="/usr/lib/spark"
cmd='$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class $MAIN_CLASS 
--name ${APPNAME}
--conf "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false"
--conf "spark.io.compression.codec=snappy"
--conf "spark.kryo.unsafe=true"
--conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=1024m"
--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
--driver-java-options "-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=$WORKER_PERM_SIZE $JAVA_OPTS"
$appdir/SomeJar.jar $APPNAME'

eval $cmd
```

Any thoughts on how to build this kind of ordering?

Comment: You can make `sparkSubmitClass.run()` synchronously wait for the shell to complete (`spark-submit` itself returns only once the job is completed), you'll have to show the implementation of `sparkSubmitClass.run()` for us to show you exactly how..

Comment: provided. sparkSubmitClass.run() basically spawns off async processes that run the sparkJob.sh scipts, which in turn submit spark jobs. Thanks for your comments so far.

Comment: @TzachZohar - I think spark-submit returns as soon as the job is submitted and not wait for the execution to be completed. But I might be wrong so correct me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing `bash scripts` and calling each job and waste io/read-write phase why don't you loop the jobs ordering as you need inside your code. 
Here's some hints for you to follow :
First you have to make sure that you have an `interface` and you implement that `interface` to every `class` you want to process in order so that you can have a common `method` to start for each jobs. (in this example the method is **process** and the interface is **JobInterface**)
Then you need to write all the `class-names-with-package` in one file with the order you want. lets say that file is `orderedJobs` (you don't need to mention extension)

```
package1.Class1
package1.Class2
package2.Class3
....
```

Read and parse that file. I am assuming it to be in resouces folder, you can filter the lines you don't want

```
val classCall = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream(<locationOforderedJobs>)).getLines().filter(!_.startsWith("#"))
```

Loop with `foreach` for each class and call the common method defined (`process`)

```
classCall.foreach(job => {
    processJob(job).process(<you can pass arguments>)
}
```

`processJob` is a `funtion` where you instantiate each class

```
def processJob(name: String): JobInterface = {
    val action = Class.forName("<package path from source root>"+className).newInstance()
    action.asInstanceOf[JobInterface]
  }
```

This way you can **reduce the io/read-write time wastage, increase spark processing efficiency by storing useful data for other jobs in-memory, reduce the processing time and many more...**
I hope it helps

Comment: This only submits the job in a particular order and does not guarantee that the next job will only be processed only once the current one has finished. But I agree on not using the shell script part. I'll replace that with SparkLauncher.

Comment: You can always use `cache` or `persist` if you don't want the job to be reprocessed. And yes `SparkLauncher` can be an alternative but is complex I guess.